Sci-Fi/Dystopia featuring cloned barmaids
I'm looking for the title of a movie I've seen on German television some 3-4 years ago. Key plot elements:

A bar where young, attractive women with fake smiles serve refreshments to middle-aged (business?-)men
The bar was extremely colorful, clean (almost sterile) and had a plasticky appearance (walls, uniforms and furniture in bright colors)
The young women were essentially cloned slaves. They were similar in appearance, but not identical
The women were drinking something from small milk cartons with straws. Their owners/employers (a company) gave it to them as a reward/after work. The women knew it wasn't really good for them, drinking too much of it had some sort of adverse effects (?). The drink was called 'soap', I believe
After a few years of service the women were told they'd get a promotion/a way out of the bar. In reality they were brought into a room with a chair, made to sit down and killed (electric shock?). Their dead bodies were hung on automatic hooks (by the ankles) and drawn, through an opening, into a factory. The viewer catches a glimpse of cloning tanks. It is clear that the dead bodies will serve as fresh organic'building material'.
At some point it is implied that their 'soap' drink is also made from processed human remains
One of the protagonists is such a cloned woman

Judging from the CGI, the movie can't be older than 1990. Most of the actors where white. The women had an American / western appearance. 
Key aspects/themes: Clones as basically worthless workers. Corporate greed. One young woman's attempt to break the cycle. Killing the clones after a few years of service (for whatever reason) and processing them into building material for new clones.
The Sci-Fi aspect wasn't all that pronounced - the classics like cloning were there but never really explained in detail.
There was little violence, as far as I remember. That's why I would call it a Sci-Fi thriller with dystopian elements.
What definitely didn't play a role: Aliens

Hate to close such a detailed question, but this is a duplicate. You're looking for Cloud Atlas. Good Q, though and welcome to M&TV!

Wonderful, many thanks.

A QUESTION is not a duplicate just because the ANSWER is the same. This is a solid question with lots of detail, and the question it supposedly duplicates is a poor question with little detail, very little of which matches. Yet you're punishing this user? And don't pretend it's not punishment.
